# What is the verb in this sentence?

Tags: bare-infinitives

I should be sleeping. 
Is "sleeping" used as adjective?

Answer (score 1):

"be sleeping" is the bare infinitive (present) in progessive form of the verb to sleep after a modal verb.

Comment: An infinitive is non-finite by definition; it has no tense and therefore cannot be marked "present".

Comment: What about infinitive perfect?

Answer (score 0):

No, "sleeping" is a verb in this sentence, the same as in the sentence:

> I am sleeping.

In this sentence, however, "sleeping" is an adjective:

> The sleeping owl had awoken.

Answer (score -1):

Sleeping would be the verb. Just like it would be in this sentence "He is sleeping".

Comment: Right. ("should" and  "be" as used here are _modal verbs_. They are auxiliary; "sleeping" is the main verb.)

Comment: *Be* is not a modal auxiliary.

Comment: @snailboat then what part of speech is that?

Comment: @Tab When *be* is an auxiliary, it's a **non-modal** auxiliary.  The English modal auxiliaries are *can, may, will, shall, must, ought, need,* and *dare*, and the non-modal auxiliaries are *be, have, do,* and for some speakers, *use*.  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, pages 92 and 108.

Comment: @snailboat okay, but is it primary auxiliary in that sentence?

Comment: or it is adjective as we can say "I should be asleep."

Comment: @Tab Yes, "asleep" is an adjective.